# How to acquire PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK in a Kivy app (Android)?

Tags: android, python, kivy, wakelock, pyjnius

I'm trying to acquire a `PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK` for my kivy app.
Basically it is a timer app, the timer should continue to run in the background when the screen has turned off. 
Everything is working fine, except for the wake lock.
This is how i would implement it in python:

```
from jnius import autoclass

PythonActivity = autoclass('org.renpy.android.PythonActivity')
activity = PythonActivity.mActivity

Context = autoclass('android.content.Context')
PowerManager = autoclass('android.os.PowerManager')

pm = activity.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE)
wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, 'TAG')

wl.acquire()
```

The app runs fine, but when the screen turns off it crashes. Applying the

```
def on_pause(self):
    return True
def on_resume(self):
    pass
```

method doesn't help me, because it stops the timer at the point where the screen turns off.

In my `buildozer.spec` file i have:

```
android.permissions = WAKE_LOCK
```

When i set:

```
android.wakelock = True
```

i only get the `screen_bright_wakelock`, but i need the `partial_wakelock`.

Answer (score 2):

I guess your misunderstood the `WAKE_LOCK` here. By default, if you don't touch the application, the system will detect the phone as Idle, and lock it.

If the user close the screen, switch to another app, etc, `WAKE_LOCK` will not do anything. Because at that point, your application must be in background, and in a "sleep" mode.

What you need is a service. A Service can continue running when the application is in background, screen locked or not. And you need communication link between your app and the service (internal OSC can be ok, feel free to search examples on the internet).

Or, try to see if AlarmManager / Alarm from the Android API can be ok with you (never tested).